# how to alloc a NSTextStorage with pre-allocated malloc'ed storage

Tags: macos, cocoa

For an NSTextStorage object, I want to set it as having malloc'ed storage coming from a 3rd party library. (The storage is special in that it is non-swappable and not to be copied.) The only possible way of doing this I could spot was maybe allocWithZone, but that is designated as no longer to be used.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Why do you need this?

Comment: The information in the storage is secure and there is to be only one copy of it in memory in a non-swappable area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSTextStorage` is documented as subclassable. As long as you implement the required primitives (listed in the [Subclassing Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextStorage_Class/index.html)), you're free to implement the backing storage any way you like.

Comment: Good point. Of course, I suppose there's no guarantee that AppKit won't make another copy of the stored data in memory (it almost certainly will, to some extent, for rendering purposes).

Comment: This looks possible. Assuming the backing store can point to a storage block of UTF-8 this should work. Thanks!

Comment: To @jtbandes's point, if you create the string with `[NSString bytesNoCopy:length:encoding:]` there's a decent chance (but no guarantee) that it won't be copied later. There isn't much reason to and AppKit would try to avoid any unnecessary copies. But there almost certainly will be glyph generation in Core Text during rendering that will encode the same information. If you're trying to avoid writing to disk, also don't forget hibernation, which writes even locked memory to `/var/vm/sleepimage`.